# what is wrong here when I sending mail?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

When I am attempting to send an email, the program throws the following Exception.

```
this:com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

#### Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    final String userName = "some@.com"; //requires valid gmail id
    final String password = "password"; // correct password for gmail id
    final String toEmail = "someemail@.com"; // can be any email id 

    System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com"); //SMTP Host
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

    //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

    EmailUtil.sendEmail(session, toEmail,"TLSEmail Testing Subject", "TLSEmail Testing Body");
}
```

Comment: maybe you have to add props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp"); Please check with it.

Comment: I can't see where you are setting the "from" address. The error is telling you, that the user you use to login to `smtp.office365.com` is not allowed to send mail from whoever you're sending the message from.  Try adding the "from" to your mail.

Comment: this userName is only my from address only I change variable name.

Comment: @Amit adding this also not working.

Comment: You can check with JavaMailSenderImpl class...

Comment: @Amit what does protocol have to do with the error `Client does not have permissions to send as this sender`?

Comment: @Philip, you are right..I am walking into wrong way.

Comment: @GauravGorde No this username is the username used to login to the server (`smtp.office365.com`).  It does not set the "from" address.

Comment: @Philip Couling usernName that I declared here same email id is this then also Exception comming.

Comment: @GauravGorde as per my answer, look in your code for "msg.setFrom"

Answer (score 1):

Right I've tracked down a copy of the code you used:

https://github.com/praveenaki/Java-Helpers/blob/master/Emailer/src/main/java/com/pvn/TLSAuthEmailer/EmailUtil.java

Please go back and read the full code.  The "from" and "to" addresses are being set in `sendEmailNow()`.  You need to set `msg.setFrom()` to the correct address or office 365 servers will reject the email.

That's what your error message means when it says:

> Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

---

For completeness I've copied the full code you copied below:

```
package com.pvn.TLSAuthEmailer;
/*
 * Refer : http://www.journaldev.com/2532/java-program-to-send-email-using-smtp-gmail-tls-ssl-attachment-image-example
 * */



import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class EmailUtil {

    /**
     * Utility method to send simple HTML email
     * @param session
     * @param toEmail
     * @param subject
     * @param body
     */
    public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body){
        try
        {
          MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          //set message headers
          msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
          msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
          msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

          msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no_reply@journaldev.com", "NoReply-JD"));

          msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("no_reply@journaldev.com", false));

          msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");

          msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");

          msg.setSentDate(new Date());

          msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
          System.out.println("Message is ready");
          Transport.send(msg);  

          System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void sendEmailNow() {
        final String fromEmail = "test@gmail.com"; //requires valid gmail id
        final String password = "********"; // correct password for gmail id
        final String toEmail = "praveen.akinapally@gmail.com"; // can be any email id 

        System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

                //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);

        EmailUtil.sendEmail(session, toEmail,"TLSEmail Testing Subject", "Balance > 100");

    }
}
```